# Tunnel interface unit-testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, unix, python-2.7, tunnel

I've made a Tun class that wraps [pytun.TunTapDevice](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pytun/2.1) :

```
from pytun import TunTapDevice

class Tun(object):
    def __init__(self,name='tun',addr=None,dstaddr=None,netmask=None,mtu=None):

        tun = TunTapDevice(name=name)
        if addr     : tun.addr      = addr
        if dstaddr  : tun.dstaddr   = dstaddr
        if netmask  : tun.netmask   = netmask
        if mtu      : tun.mtu       = mtu
        self._tun = tun
        self.up = self._tun.up
        self.down = self._tun.down
        self.read = self._tun.read
        self.write = self._tun.write
        self.close = self._tun.close


    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._tun.name

    @property
    def mtu(self):
        return self._tun.mtu
```

The question is not about how to write a tunnel, but about how to write a test-case to ensure it works properly in unix-like oses using python unit-testing.

What should I write out to it to ensure is works? Maybe an ARP request, ICMP, DNS packet or anything else:

```
class TestTunnel(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.tun = Tun(name='tun0', addr='192.168.0.23', netmask='255.255.255.0',mtu=1500)

    def test_tunnel(self):
        self.tun.write(?????)
        self.assertEqual(self.tun.read(),????)
```

EDIT 1:

finally i got it by this code:

```
from select import select
import dpkt
import struct

class TunnelTestCase( unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.tun = Tun(name='testtun',
                       addr='192.168.6.92',
                       dstaddr='192.168.6.93',
                       netmask='255.255.255.0', 
                       mtu=1500)
        self.tun.up()

    def _ip2str(self,ip):
        return '.'.join([str(i) for i in struct.unpack('!BBBB',ip)])

    def test_echo(self):
        reqPack = dpkt.ip.IP('E\x00\x00T\x00\x00@\x00@\x01\xac\x9f\xc0\xa8\x06]\xc0\xa8\x06\\\x08\x00\x1c\xae\t\xc7\x00\x01\x0f\x8adQq\xab\x01\x00\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./01234567')
        self.tun.write(reqPack.pack())

        r,_w,_ex = select([self.tun],[],[],4)
        if len(r) and r[0] == self.tun:
            replyPack = dpkt.ip.IP(self.tun.read())
            self.assertEqual(self._ip2str(replyPack.src), self.tun.addr)
            self.assertEqual(self._ip2str(replyPack.dst), self.tun.dstaddr)
            return

        self.assert_(False, 'ICMP Echo timeout, the tunnel interface may not works properly in your system.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply be able to borrow the test cases from pytun and simplify them. In fact, I think that testing actual connectivity is done in their package, so unless you are trying to test something significantly different, you might be able to get away with just running there tests without modification. https://github.com/montag451/pytun/tree/master/test

Since it's a raw socket, you can simply try to send a plain ascii message from the client and verify it is received by the server, and then have the server send back an acknowledgement, which you can assert against.

Comment: I need to test the tun automatically,the montag test needs to run from command prompt and pass some arguments to work. so i plan to write two sockets in server-client manner, to communicate across the tunnel interface. client send anything and server just echo whatever receives. whats your idea?

Comment: I would just do the setup of the server inside the setUp method and pass in what would previously be passed in by hand through the command line. You may need to fork it on another thread since it may be blocking (that also means you need a way to kill that other thread). Yeah just do a simple echo "Hello World" from the client and assert against that when reading data out of the socket for both the server and the client. You can do all the setup in an automated fashion, no need to have to setup the server by hand by passing command line arguments just to run the test.